# Подключение к HIVE Hadoop

Tags: c#, hadoop, hive

Есть бд которая находится на сервере обращаюсь туда через браузер типа http://00.00.00.000:0000 хотелось бы подключиться к Hive Hadoop через .net c#.
Пробовал через Microsoft.Hadoop.Hive;

```
var db = new HiveConnection(
webHCatUri: (new Uri("http://00.00.00.000:0000/accounts/login/")),
userName: "логин", password: "пароль");
var result = db.ExecuteHiveQuery(query: "select count(*) from edw_uat_odl.t_ABONENT where package_id = 15");
result.Wait();
```

Не возвращает результат и в db hostname=null.

Когда логинишься через браузер POST отправляет параметры

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken "7e9001a3c2801f25097c11e119745e31"
username    "логин"
password    "пароль"
next    "/about/"
```

Когда делаю запрос в самом Hive через Besswax отправляю параметры

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken "7e9001a3c2801f25097c11e119745e31"
query-database  "default"
settings-0-key  "mapreduce.job.queuename"
settings-0-value    "EK"
settings-0-_exists  "True"
query-is_parameterized  "on"
query-download_format   "None"
query-query "set+hive.mapred.mode=unstrict;set+mapreduce.job.queuename=EK;select+count(*)+    from+edw_uat_odl.t_ABONENT+where+package_id+=+15"
settings-next_form_id   "1"
file_resources-next_form_id "0"
functions-next_form_id  "0"
button-submit   "Execute"
```

Вообщем просьба подсказать как оправлять запросы в hive и получать ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Ставлю на то, что проблема в:

```
webHCatUri: (new Uri("http://00.00.00.000:0000/accounts/login/")),
```

- судя по `/accounts/login`, вы скопировали это из браузера, в котором открывали что-то типа Hue.

WebHCat - это совсем не то, это т.н. REST API к HCatalog: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+UsingWebHCat

В [работающих](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18127617/1026) [примерах](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn749872.aspx) видно, что если статус WebHCat доступен по адресу http://www.myserver.com/templeton/v1/status , то в `webHCatUri:` указывается `new Uri("http://www.myserver.com")`

Соответственно, для отладки подключения нужно использовать curl: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-use-hive-curl